# The type "AppListEntry" exists in both Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET and Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, .net-5

I have an app (.NET 5.0) which references another project (.NET Core 2.1) via nuget (not publically available).

When I reference this project, the following line throws up an error:

```
AppListEntry appListEntry = await InstallUWPFromStoreAsync(appTest.CatalogId);
```

Error:

> The type 'AppListEntry' exists in both 'Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET,
> Version=10.0.17763.22, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' and
> 'Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract, Version=10.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'

Is there a way to override which library should be the global source of truth for the application?

**Update**

Adding a fully qualified reference doesn't seem to resolve the issue:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways you could disambiguate your references to `AppListEntry`.

You could fully qualify individual references:

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.AppListEntry appListEntry =
    await InstallUWPFromStoreAsync(appTest.CatalogId);
```

Alternatively, you could use a *using alias* (typically placed with your other using directives):

```
using AppListEntry = Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.AppListEntry;
...
AppListEntry appListEntry = await InstallUWPFromStoreAsync(appTest.CatalogId);
```

If you're using C# 10 or later, you could make the using alias *global*, which would apply it to all files in the compilation (while only declaring it in one file):

```
global using AppListEntry = Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.AppListEntry;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this doesn't resolve the issue unfortunetely:
The type 'AppListEntry' exists in both 'Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET, Version=10.0.17763.22, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' and 'Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime' AutoPlusConsoleApp C:\Program.cs

Comment: @TomSelleck See here for more info about error CS0433: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0433. You might be able to fix the problem by editing your .csproj file(s) as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/inputs#references.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing the following.

1. Open your Nuget Package reference Properties.
2. Provide new Alias for the reference, say `another`.
3. Open your file and add this line `extern alias another;` before your namespace declaration.
4. Now change your erroneous line to

   var appListEntry = await another::{Full Name of the locating namespace of the another library}.InstallUWPFromStoreAsync(appTest.CatalogId);

See details about [extern keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx)